# Two periods required?

Tags: punctuation, parentheses, periods

When a sentence ends with a parenthetical statement which itself ends with a period, does the sentence also need a period? Example:

> I love eating vegetables (carrots, peas, etc.).

The two periods don't look correct, but seem technically correct.

Comment: The full stop after etc. is not there to mark the end of a clause. It is there in recognition of etc. being an abbreviation. Had the etc. not appeared you would not, presumably have placed a stop after 'peas'. Had you have done it would have been quite unnecessary. If my sentence ends in etc., or some other abbreviation, I always place two stops.

Answer (score 2):

Both periods are necessary: the first so that "etc" is a properly written abbreviation, and the second to terminate the sentence after the parenthesis.

On the other hand, if the sentence had ended in an abbreviation (not inside parentheses), then [two consecutive periods would not have been necessary](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28518/16310).

Answer (score 1):

The  tendency in BrE is not to use a full stop after abbreviations, so there is no problem here. We write *I love eating vegetables (carrots, peas, etc).*

Answer (score -2):

yes and, in your example there should not be a comma after "peas"

Comment: [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1470/16310) disagrees with your suggestion to omit the comma before "etc."