# Why do we use a comma before "and"?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma before last item in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/comma-before-last-item-in-a-list)

Often times, I find myself writing sentences like the following:

> "... to integrate four granularities
>   of features: first, second, third, and
>   fourth."

I am just curious to find out if there should be a comma before and. Can someone explain the reason for having (or not having) the comma?