# Usage of 'and' with commas

Tags: american-english, british-english, commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma before last item in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/comma-before-last-item-in-a-list)

I grew up learning British English rules and we were taught that while using commas to list or enumerate items, there should **never** be a comma before the *and*. For instance:

> I bought bread, milk, apples and oranges.

I've seen this rule less prominent these days, especially in the US. The same sentence would be:

> I bought bread, milk, apples, and oranges.

While this usage would have my English teachers up in arms, it seems quite normal here. Is it more of a pseudo-archaic use, is it more enforced in British English?