# comma question: (one, two, and three) vs. (one, two and three)

Tags: commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma before last item in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/comma-before-last-item-in-a-list)

When listing items in a sentence, is it more acceptable to omit the comma between the penultimate and last item?  (assume there will always be an "and" between these two items).