# Comma usage for multiple words

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, commas, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comma before last item in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/comma-before-last-item-in-a-list)

Is it correct to write:

> 1. a,b, or c
> 2. a,b, and c

Is the comma used after *b* correct?