# Enumerations and conjunctions "and" and "or"

Tags: grammar, commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

How do I know if I need to add a comma or not before a conjunction preceding the last item in an enumeration?

For example, which of the following sentences is correct?

> I have a house, a car, a bicycle, and an airplane.
>
> I have a house, a car, a bicycle and an airplane.

Are there any *free* online references on this matter (with examples, if possible) for the layman?