# Should I use the so-called Oxford comma, or not?

Tags: commas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

Until relatively recent times, I always concluded a series in this manner, eg.: "while walking through the park yesterday, I saw dogs, pigs, kangaroos, mountain lions, zebras and wolves.

Eventually, it occurred to me that, for clarity's sake, that is to indicate that the last two items mentioned are not related as a pair, I should end such a sentence as "...mountain lions, zebras, and wolves." I read that this use of the comma is called an "Oxford" commma.

I think that the former use has just an aesthetic appeal, whereas the latter use has a more practical, clarifying function. I'm inclined, these days, to use the latter style.

Is this indeed the "Oxford" comma, and, if so, is it considered correct, incorrect, or just a matter of preference?

Thanks,

-Gavin

Comment: Welcome, Gavin, but I have voted to close your question because I think you will find the answer has already been provided elsewhere.

Comment: @Gnawme Although the other question has an accepted answer, it is not locked; you can add another answer there if you think that the existing answers do not fully answer the question. You can also comment on existing answers that you think can be improved or even make edits that improve them, if you can do so while respecting their authors' efforts. (Doing these things can help to make a more thorough and authoritative single post, making that question more useful as a reference for those who have the same or similar questions.)

Comment: @aediaλ: OK, thanks. In that case, I withdraw my answer, and add my close vote.

Comment: I was eager to participate and didn't see the question elsewhere, though my search was rather cursory. I will be careful when I wish to ask another question, and double-check! Thank you for the welcome.