# Sentence with multiple 'and's: should I use an Oxford comma, and if so, where?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I have the following sentence:

> I am a self-starter possessing excellent problem solving ability and outstanding coordination and communication skills.

Using the Oxford comma, what is the correct way to write it?

> I am a self-starter possessing excellent problem solving ability, and outstanding coordination and communication skills.

> I am a self-starter possessing excellent problem solving ability and outstanding coordination, and communication skills.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this is OP's sixth question, all of which seem to be concerned with nothing more than helping him write his job application, phrase by phrase.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: as long as each question is valid, I don't see a problem with all of them having the same ultimate purpose.

Comment: FumbleFingers thanks for your time. Please mention how it against site's policy. If it is against site policy it should be closed.

I have put a question which I don't know about. I have mention an example where I am seeking guidance.

Comment: @user576510: As I've said many times before, it's not really my concern whether your questions violate the exact wording of ELU's "site policy". Without wishing to be derogatory to you personally, I do not think the level of questions you ask are of interest to *linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.* If others agree, your questions will be closed. If not - well, I'm just one voice trying to push the site in a direction I would prefer.

Comment: ...also note that this specific question has been [asked more than once before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50857/), and was in fact answered quite concisely [very early in the life of the site](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, those questions are all asking about the actual serial comma, i.e. involving an actual list rather than just a pair of items. As such, their answers don't really apply here. (I was trying to edit out the "oxford comma" mentions from the question, but I was afraid of changing the OP's intent too drastically.)

Comment: @Marthaª: Well, maybe it's just me, but I fail utterly to see the difference between this "non-Oxford comma" question, and [OP's earlier one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60190/) asking about *"I am a software developer who has permanent residence, Bachelor degree and 4 years experience in .net for developing new software and doing enhancements in existing once."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, how you connect two different questions ? You are connecting an other questions's example with this question and concluding something wrong.

Comment: @user576510: In this example your final *"and"* connects both *"coordination"* and *"communication skills"* to the preceding word *"outstanding"*. In the earlier one, the final *"and"* connects *"developing new software"* and *"doing enhancements in existing ones"* to the preceding *"4 years experience in .net"*. There is no difference. Also I notice you have ignored Peter Shor's well-meant advice, and not bothered to edit *"once"* to *"ones"* in that earlier question. There is more wrong with your English than ELU can be expected to help with.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If he's really working on a résumé, as you infer, I have no problem with that - so long as he takes us all out to lunch after he lands a job ;^)

Comment: @J.R.: He might be aiming for a position at one of those American colleges where academic potential is secondary to being able to help their team win in some sports league. In which case *"outstanding"* may only be intended to modify *"coordination"* (he's got good physical coordination on the football field). The *"communication skills"* may be just adequate for performing well on the pitch. I do despair of the fact that this all makes me seem even more grouchy than I am, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The serial comma only comes into play if you have an actual list, i.e. three or more items. You only have two:

> excellent problem solving ability

and

> outstanding coordination and communications skills

To see this, look at the nouns, not the phrases describing them: *ability* and *skills* are two things.

Within the phrase "outstanding coordination and communications skills", it is absolutely wrong to insert a comma before the "and". For the sentence as a whole, though, the issue isn't quite so clear-cut: it's not really a list, so adding a comma is unnecessary, but on the other hand, it can aid comprehension to group the adjectival phrases — basically, to make it clear that *excellent problem solving* goes with *ability*, while *outstanding coordination and communications* all go with *skills*.