# When do I add a comma before an "and"?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

Sometimes, I see an extra comma before an "and" but I don't know when I should and should not add a comma before an "and". For example:

> There are apples, oranges *and* pears in the basket.

In this sentence, I don't think that there is no need for a comma before the "and pears". But sometimes, I see sentences having commas before "and". For example:

> I have eaten my dinner, and I am ready go out.

In this case, is the comma before the "and" necessary? In longer sentences, I often see a mixture of with and without comma before "and". In what scenario should I then add a comma before the "and" in a sentence?

Comment: Just always do it as a matter of policy. Someday you’ll thank me.