# proper way to use a comma separating 3 (or more) words in a sentence

Tags: conjunctions, commas, lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

Proper English writing is not my strong point so I thought I'd post a question here.

Using the following as an example:

> Discover new ways to search, browse, and discover things that may interest you.

Is it correct to have the comma before the 'and' or not? I've always struggled with this issue and I've never really known the correct answer, so can someone let me know?