# Is it alright to use the word "and" immediately after a comma?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

I was taught in my school that the following is wrong:

> Tom, Dick, and Harry went to school on Thursday.

Instead, the correct form is:

> Tom, Dick and Harry went to school on Thursday.

The reasoning I was taught is that it's wrong to use "and" immediately after a comma (conversely, it's wrong to precede the word "and" with a comma). I am highly suspicious of what I was taught in my school. Can someone confirm or refute the above thesis with a strong reference?