# Should there be a comma before ‘and’ with respect to different nouns?

Tags: commas, conjunctions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

> What is the difference between tomato puree, ***paste, and sauce***?

OR

> What is the difference between tomato puree, ***paste and sauce***?

Do we need a comma before *and* in this case?