# What is an Oxford comma and how do you use it?

Tags: punctuation, commas

I didn't even know this existed. What is it? How do you use it?

Comment: Have you done a search here for "oxford comma"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oxford Comma Conventions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172671/oxford-comma-conventions); see the Katz answer which makes a lot of sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: See also "[Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)" The highest-voted answer to that question explains pretty well what the Oxford comma is and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oxford comma is a comma that is placed after the penultimate item [second or last] in a list before an 'and' or an 'or'. This only applies to lists of three or more items. Oxford commas are completely optional and remain at a matter of dispute, some people use them, while others don't.

*Example*

- I bought cheese, crackers, and a sandwich.
- I like cheese and crackers is correct, the rule of the oxford comma only applies to *sentences of that are three or more items long*
- There were many animals at the Bronx Zoo, tigers, monkeys, toucans, and orangutans were my favourite. Notice the comma after 'toucans'.