# Regarding Punctuation

Tags: american-english, oxford-comma

**Which of the following is correct ?**

**1)  A, B, C and D**

**2)  A, B, C, and D**

Comment: Wars have been started over less!

Comment: As shown, with a simplified formulaic example, this seems to be a purely style-driven choice. But as shown in @Adam Katz's answer in [this duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172671/oxford-comma-conventions) (original article by Joe Kessler), sometimes the Oxford comma (aka serial comma) is better included, sometimes it is better omitted, for clarity.