# When to put comma only or comma with conjunctions to separate items inside brackets (,) (, and )

Tags: commas, oxford-comma

I was wondering about when to put comma only or comma with connectors to separate items inside brackets (,) (, and ).

This is an example:

> Health status (physical, mental, biological, psychological)

or

> Health status (physical, mental, biological and psychological)

Comment: I don't think it matters. The normal rules about grammar in sentences don't apply to the bit in brackets.

Comment: While grammar doesn't disappear out of the window for parentheticals, there can be a relaxation. But your examples are insufficient. In running text, I'd use the normal listing format << Health status (physical, mental, biological, and psychological) is regularly monitored. >> (Note that the Oxford comma forces 4 list members here.) If your NP example is a chapter heading, the terser format becomes more (if not perhaps _the_ more) attractive.

Comment: I don't use Oxford comma in this essay. Do I have to make an exception and use it in the brackets?

Comment: ... The best answer (by [Adam Katz, quoting Joe Kessler](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172671/oxford-comma-conventions)) to the question asked here about whether the Oxford comma should be used was essentially 'To disambiguate, sometimes the Oxford comma is necessary, sometimes it is deleterious'.