# How to use a Comma

Tags: commas

Signing a tribute.  Which way is correct?

Liz, Fred, and Nicole

or

Liz, Fred and Nicole

Comment: Basically, it depends on what sort of shoe you wear.  If you wear low-heal, lace-up leather shoes then you use the extra comma.

Comment: Not putting a comma after Fred might be interpreted that Fred and Nicole are a couple.

Comment: (You basically have to decide which group of people you want to offend.  Of course, both groups are well-educated and know that they're right.)

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are correct.

The comma before the last item in the series (the comma after "Fred") is known as the "serial comma" or "Oxford comma." Whether one uses it is mostly a matter of preference, or house style. You can find reams of information about it on the Web and elsewhere. There's also this discussion:
[Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Academic writing would require the Oxford comma to clarify the intended meaning of the list.  For example, without the last comma after Fred, one could interpret from the sentence that Fred and Nicole are a couple.