# Is it correct to use "and" consecutively without a comma?

Tags: commas

> Your last day of service will be mutually agreed between you and your
>   manager and details sent in writing by Human Resources.

I think it doesn't make sense to interpret this sentence as "**the last day is agreed between you, your manager, and details from Human Resources**". So, I think "are" is missing for the part "details sent in writing by Human Resources", which means that it should have been written in "details are sent in writing by Human Resources". But in this case, shouldn't there be a comma right before the second "and" since the following sentence is a separate one not sharing the subject?

Comment: There is a similar discussion about the use of the comma in a list - the Oxford Comma - in this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list

Comment: The wording is atrocious. Please do not try to parse it. Do not guess but get a clarification from the source.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct.

It seems the intention is that you & your manager will talk, and at some shortly following future time, HR will send the agreed-to specific details in writings.  Because you & your boss are living humans who can talk to each other, it doesn't make sense to make a mutual agreement with a dead-tree document HR already sent which cannot enter a conversational negotiation with either one of you.