# What is the correct way to punctuate this text?

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence, adverbs, oxford-comma

I would like to know your thoughts on how to correctly punctuate this text:

**One of the most visited places here in Manila is Binondo, often referred to as the business capital at the time, before housing little towns and narrow sidewalks. Specifically near the shorelines of Pasig River therefore making it perfect for travelling by boat, trade and commerce possibly routed through and from Binondo.**

(This is from a blog post, which you can read from this link: http://www.rochellerivera.com/2019/04/what-it-really-feels-like-to-live-in.html)

I have 4 things to point out:

First, the second sentence here is not a sentence at all. Where is the subject? Can we even connect it to the first sentence? Can we make it "sidewalks, specifically"?

Second, do we need to put a comma after "Specifically"?

Third, do we need to enclose "therefore" with commas?

Fourth, do we need to have a comma between "trade" & "commerce"?

Thank you!

Comment: The whole blog is written in poor English. The example you gives needs rewriting completely. Unfortunately, merely correcting the punctuation is not going to help at all, and proofreading is not done by EL&U.

Comment: @Greybeard I only need to correct the punctuations or the lack of them.

Comment: It cannot be punctuated because it is wrong.

Comment: I agree with @Greybeard. All sentences need to be rewritten. But here is a  helpful post for the Oxford comma: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list/413

Comment: I agree with @Greybeard. Punctuation alone won't help.

Comment: The "best of the worst" I can think of with respect to punctuation is to use dashes and parentheses. They serve to (somewhat) distract from the sentences actually being ungrammatical. *One of the most visited places here in Manila is Binondo—often referred to as the business capital at the time before housing little towns and narrow sidewalks. Specifically, near the shorelines of Pasig River—therefore making it perfect for travelling by boat, trade and commerce (possibly routed through and from Binondo).*