# Explain why this sentence is incorrect

Tags: grammaticality

The printer only works with expensive, blue ink cartridges.

and

He found a tarnished, gold coin on the beach.

Comment: What source has indicated that it *is* incorrect?

Comment: The teacher only said the comma was incorrect and asked to explain why.... im lost :(

Comment: They are not "wrong".  They are not idiomatic.

Comment: They can't be idiomatic because they're writing. The sentences are not incorrect. Their punctuation is wrong because a comma has been used in a place where it should not go. this is strictly about punctuation, not grammar or English.

Comment: Right now, we read that the beach coin was both tarnished and gold, rather than a coin of tarnished gold. The comma replaces *and*, but the sentence makes more sense without the *and*.

Comment: A coin of actual gold would not be tarnished. Though often alloyed with other metals gold coins are normally corrosion free.

Answer (score -2):

What is the state of the coin? Is it *tarnished and gold* (separate adjectives)? or is it *tarnished gold* (as a conjoined adjectival phrase defining a colour). Either would be acceptable.

But *... a tarnished, gold coin* reads like the start of a list of adjectives where - erroneously - no third or following adjectives are given. An example might be *... a tarnished, gold and battered coin*. From this viewpoint, the comma in the question is disruptive and unnecessary.

There is a relevant but long (not "*relevant, long set*") set of answers about the use of commas in listing in [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list)