# Why don't we need a comma here?

Tags: commas, writing-style

I'm wondering why a comma is not necessary after the word *cheekbones*. Is there a rule for this?

> He didn’t pay much attention to the movie. At least, he had been thinking he didn’t until he felt warm, salty tears running down from the corners of his eyes, slowing down on the sharp edges of his cheekbones and speeding up again after reaching the slope right under them.

Comment: [Such questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list) have come up veeery often. The conclusion is that it is a matter of stylistic choice, or simply opinion, which _[whispering]_ is a taboo here...

Comment: The "Oxford Comma" (https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/?gclid=CjwKCAjwo_KXBhAaEiwA2RZ8hGchkOfQ-AYUEB3GmiJB8a9X-h3BzaSfEqGA_MDmv9LhjMdgQhJGMRoCV9YQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) is optional in most cases.

Comment: ... Yes, the list here is of three ing-clauses: << salty tears **(a)** running down from the corners of his eyes, **(b)** slowing down on the sharp edges of his cheekbones and **(c)** speeding up again ....>>. It sounds a bit awkward/contrived in my opinion, but I'd certainly not favour the comma and its associated pause before _and_ (though it wouldn't be proscribed).